# How to show a list of TODO entries without timestamps?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I would like to have an agenda view that would contain all TODO entries that do not have timestamps associated with them.

From Org info i found that variables `org-agenda-todo-ignore-with-date` and `org-agenda-todo-ignore-timestamp` are provided for that purpose. However, i would like to keep original "all TODO entries in `org-agenda-files`" view intact.

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my set-up I have the following customization

```
'(org-agenda-custom-commands
   (quote
    (("d" "Undated tasks" alltodo ""
      ((org-agenda-todo-ignore-with-date t))))))
```

which makes `C-a d` give me a list of tasks that have no date.  Here is the customization buffer version of this:

```
Org Agenda Custom Commands:
INS DEL Choice: Value Menu Single command:
            Access Key(s) : d
            [X] Description: Undated tasks
            Choice: Value Menu TODO list
            Match (only for some commands): 
            Local settings for this command.  Remember to quote values:
            INS DEL Setting: Value Menu Any variable:
                        Variable: org-agenda-todo-ignore-with-date
                        Value (sexp): t
            INS
            [ ] Export:
                INS
INS
    State : SAVED and set.
```